# guardo un archivo txt en una variable y la uso de parametro en dos funciones pero solo funciona bien en la primer funcion que ponga

Tags: python

Guardo el archivo de texto en una variable, uso esa variable como argumento en dos funciones, solo funciona bien la primer función que ponga, osea:

```
archivo = open("archivo.txt")
funcionUno(archivo) #<-- Esta funciona bien, porque fue la primera
funcionDos(archivo) #<--- Esta funciona mal, como que no lee el archivo
```

Pero si lo hago al revés:

```
funcionDos(archivo) #<--- Funciona bien
funcionUno(archivo) #<--- Funciona mal
```

######################################

La solución que encontré fue usar la funcion `open()` por cada funcion, o sea:

```
archivo = open("archivo.txt")
funcionUno(archivo) <-- Funciona bien

archivo = open("archivo.txt")
funcionDos(archivo) <-- Funciona bien
```

Se que algo estoy haciendo mal ¿Alguien sabe que pasa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nota: El error lo dedusco por el escenario, pero la proxima, ten en cuenta que si proporcionas un pequeño código que tenga el mismo error, sería más facil ayudarte.

Por cierto, una pregunta interesante c:

---

#### Concepto

La cuestión tiene relación con como funciona la lectura de los archivos en python.

En Python, los archivos se manejan con un cursor. Este cursor se parece mucho conceptualmente a un cursor de los que verías en programas como world, el bloc de notas o incluso en este sitio, aquel que indica donde se escribe el texto o se selecciona.

El cursor es el punto de referencia que usan las funciones read y write para saber desde donde leer y escribir respectivamente y está al comienzo o al final del archivo en modo lectura y escritura respectivamente.

El método read lee x caracteres, aunque por default, lee hasta el final del archivo. Luego mueve el cursor justo después del ultimo caracter leido.

#### Ejemplos

Supongo que con lo que dije, ya tendrás claro que sucede, pero mejoraré igualmente con ejemplos.
El cursor es el caracter "|"

```
|hola mundo
```

Ejecutamos `print(file.read(2))`, lo que lee los siguientes dos caracteres (marcados en asterisco)

```
|*ho*la mundo
```

Y nos muestra `ho` en consola, moviendo el cursor dos caracteres

```
ho|la mundo
```

Finalmente, decidimos leer el resto `print(file.read())`, lo que produce `la mundo`

#### Solución

Como podrás ver, en la primera llamada al método read, lees todo el archivo. Pero en la segunda llamada, como el cursor ya está al final del archivo y no queda nada para leer, te devuelve una cadena vacía.

Entonces, movamos el cursor de nuevo al principio antes de leer. Esto lo podemos lograr agregando la siguiente linea antes de todas las lecturas destinadas a leer el archivo completo (opcional para la primera lectura)

```
file.seek(0)
```

Esto se encarga de mover el cursor a la posición absoluta 0 (el inicio del archivo). Si estás interesado, [en google](https://www.google.com/search?q=seek+python&oq=seek+python&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l2j0i22i30l7.5236j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) se explica con más detalle esta función. También está en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek)

#### Un pequeño consejo

Usar read carga los caracteres a leer en la memoria. Eso significa que usar read en archivos demasiado grandes (0,5 gb por ejemplo) para leerlos enteros entero resulte en un uso excesivo de memoria o que directamente no alcance dicha, dando un MemoryError.

Si no se requiere tener todo el archivo en memoria en simultaneo, habitualmente  resulta mejor iterar sobre el archivo linea por linea. Esto utiliza el cursor y lo mueve automaticamente según sea necesario para leer una linea a la vez del archivo.

```
for line in file:
    [codigo]
```

Solo ten en cuenta que la variable line incluye el caracter de escape "\n", que representa el cambio entre una linea y otra. Lo podés eliminar con linea.rstrip("\n").

Si no querés linea por linea, podés leer el archivo a partes, usando algo como:

```
while True:
    chunk = file.read(10)
 
    if not chunk:
        break

    [codigo]
```

Comment: Me lo explicaste excelente, muchas gracias, era eso